# Join 2 lists in share point using CAML query

Tags: sharepoint

I just use Sharepoint for few days and I know this question have asked many times but I've tried all of them and none of them work.

These are my design

- Document as a Document Library type have a Id

  ```
  Id | DocumentName
  ---+-------------
  1  | Document A
  2  | Document B
  ```
- Activities list, have a foreign key 'DocId' that reference to the Document Id

  ```
  Id | DocId | Name
  ---+-------+-----------
  1  | 1     | Activity A
  2  | 1     | Activity B
  3  | 1     | Activity C
  4  | 2     | Activity D
  ```

The Problem is I need to get all the Activities that included the document name on the Document.

In SQL I can use Join query to get the additional information from another table. But I have try some Join statement in CAML query and none of them work.
Here is the result that I need to get.

```
Id | DocId | Name       | DocumentName
---+-------+--------------------------
1  | 1     | Activity A | Document A
2  | 1     | Activity B | Document A
3  | 1     | Activity C | Document A
4  | 2     | Activity D | Document B
```

Could any one please suggest me the query?

Here is my query:

```
<View>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name = 'DocLeafRef'/>
    <FieldRef Name = 'ID'/>
    <FieldRef Name = 'e8_document'/>
    <FieldRef Name = 'Title'/>
    <FieldRef Name = 'Author'/>
    <FieldRef Name = 'Created'/>
  </ViewFields>
  <Joins>
    <Join Type = 'INNER' ListAlias = 'Documents'>
      <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name ='e8_document' RefType = 'Id'/>
         <FieldRef Name ='ID' List ='Documents'/>
      </Eq>
    </Join>
  </Joins>
  <ProjectedFields>
    <Field ShowField ='FileLeafRef' Type ='Lookup' Name ='DocLeafRef' List ='Documents'/>
  </ProjectedFields>
  <Query>
     <Where>
        <Eq>
           <FieldRef Name='e8_caseId'></FieldRef>
           <Value Type = 'Number'>23</Value>
        </Eq>
     </Where>
  </Query>
</View>
```

I'm query on the Activities list and the e8_document is the lookup field that reference to the Id in the Document. As I understand we need the projection and I've added the projection but the query throws an error.

Comment: Can you post the CAML query that you've tried which gave you the above result? Then we can tell you how to correct it using [list joins and projections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539975%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: @Thriggle I add my query, could you please help me whats wrong with the query

Answer (score 1):

It seems the `Query` element is invalid in your case, basically `Query` element could not contain [`Joins`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee535493(v=office.14).aspx) as a child element.

**Server-Side Object Model**

For [`SPQuery Class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery(v=office.14).aspx) [`Joins` element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee535493(v=office.14).aspx) needs to be specified via [`SPQuery.Joins` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.joins(v=office.14).aspx):

```
var qry = new SPQuery();
qry.Joins = @"<Join Type="LEFT" ListAlias="Documents">
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="DocId" RefType="ID" />
                <FieldRef Name="ID" List="Documents" />
            </Eq>
        </Join>";
```

**Client-Side Object Model**

Here is the complete CAML query for *CSOM API*:

```
<View>
    <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name="ID" />
        <FieldRef Name="DocId" />
        <FieldRef Name="Name" />
        <FieldRef Name="Documents" />
    </ViewFields>
    <Joins>
        <Join Type="LEFT" ListAlias="Documents">
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="DocId" RefType="ID" />
                <FieldRef Name="ID" List="Documents" />
            </Eq>
        </Join>
    </Joins>
    <ProjectedFields>
        <Field ShowField="DocumentName" Type="Lookup" Name="Documents" List="Documents" />
    </ProjectedFields>
    <Query />
</View>
```

Comment: Hi i apply your query but i get the error from SharePoint client: One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields. Is there something wrong with my query

Comment: In my second example the name of lookup field is DocId, given your example you probably need to replace it with e8_document, there are two occurrences, one in ViewFields element, another one in Join element

Comment: I have one more problem with the <ProjectedFields> as the query above a need the FileLeafRef in the foreign list which is "File" type and i get the error "Value does not fall within the expected range". Does this error cause by the file is to long or the File type need another way to get

Comment: could you please take a look at this